# Apache Rule Rewrite Map Regular Expression

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite

Hey i am trying to create a redirect map but the links i am trying to redirect are generated and just the ID number at the end is what matters.
I would like to know how can i redirect based on skipping everything in front of the last hyphen "-" in the url.

URL that i am trying to redirect:

```
    http://staging.mysite.com/discover/en/suppliers/TD-Machi-LC-363868
    but can be any possible combination:
    http://staging.mysite.com/discover/en/suppliers/TD-Machining-101-LCC-363868
    http://staging.mysite.com/discover/en/suppliers/Ted-Baker-D-363868
    http://staging.mysite.com/discover/en/suppliers/363868
```

My current redirect that i was trying to get to work is:

```
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteMap discovertxt txt:/opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs/maps/discover_all_map.txt
    RewriteMap discoverdestinationtxt txt:/opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs/maps/discover_destination_map.txt
    RewriteMap discoversourcetxt txt:/opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs/maps/discover_source_map.txt
    # Discover Redirect
    # RewriteCond ${discoverdestinationtxt:$1} >${discoversourcetxt:$1} [NC]
    
    # Trying to capture only the last value of the string
    RewriteRule ^/discover/en/suppliers/^(.*)-(.*)-(.*)-(.*) /manufacturer/${discovertxt:$4}/ [R=301,L]
    
    # Bellow method works only if ID alone is supplied.
    # RewriteRule ^/discover/en/suppliers/(.*) /manufacturer/${discovertxt:$1}/ [R=301,L]
    
    </IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer for how to search for exact ID match within string:

```
    RewriteRule ^/discover/en/suppliers/(.*)([0-9]{6}) /manufacturer/${discover:$2}/ [R=301]
```